# Libgdx scene2d uiskin.json com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException

Tags: java, json, libgdx, scene2d

So, I copied the raw from the Libgdx uiskin.json file from their [GitHub](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data/uiskin.json) but when I attempt to run my project I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UISkin/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.MainMenu.setup(MainMenu.java:65)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.MainMenu.show(MainMenu.java:22)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.Loader$1.run(Loader.java:31)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.run(RunnableAction.java:42)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.RunnableAction.act(RunnableAction.java:32)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.SequenceAction.act(SequenceAction.java:65)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.act(Actor.java:95)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.act(Group.java:49)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:223)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.act(Stage.java:186)
at com.kappaDelta.espRPG.Loader.render(Loader.java:42)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:215)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: UISkin/uiskin.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:683)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
... 16 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No Drawable, NinePatch, TextureRegion, Texture, or Sprite registered with name: white
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getDrawable(Skin.java:283)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.newDrawable(Skin.java:315)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$5.read(Skin.java:489)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:867)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:404)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:834)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.readNamedObjects(Skin.java:425)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:414)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$2.read(Skin.java:410)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.readValue(Json.java:867)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$1.readValue(Skin.java:404)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:681)
... 17 more
```

I've spent about half an hour searching through google for any similar problem, but to no avail.

Here's the other files

uiskin.json:

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file:    Font/Gabriola.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
green: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 1, r: 0 },
white: { a: 1, b: 1, g: 1, r: 1 },
red: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 1 },
black: { a: 1, b: 0, g: 0, r: 0 },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin$TintedDrawable: {
dialogDim: { name: white, color: { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0, a: 0.45 } },
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$ButtonStyle: {
default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round },
toggle: { down: default-round-down, checked: default-round-down, up: default-round }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font, fontColor: white },
toggle: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, checked: default-round-down, font: default-font, fontColor: white, downFontColor: red }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ScrollPane$ScrollPaneStyle: {
default: { vScroll: default-scroll, hScrollKnob: default-round-large, background: default-rect, hScroll: default-scroll, vScrollKnob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SelectBox$SelectBoxStyle: {
default: {
    font: default-font, fontColor: white, background: default-select,
    scrollStyle: default,
    listStyle: { font: default-font, selection: default-select-selection }
}
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.SplitPane$SplitPaneStyle: {
default-vertical: { handle: default-splitpane-vertical },
default-horizontal: { handle: default-splitpane }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
default: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white },
dialog: { titleFont: default-font, background: default-window, titleFontColor: white, stageBackground: dialogDim }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ProgressBar$ProgressBarStyle: {
default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: {
default-horizontal: { background: default-slider, knob: default-slider-knob },
default-vertical: { background: default-slider, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
default: { font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextField$TextFieldStyle: {
default: { selection: selection, background: textfield, font: default-font, fontColor: white, cursor: cursor }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.CheckBox$CheckBoxStyle: {
default: { checkboxOn: check-on, checkboxOff: check-off, font: default-font, fontColor: white }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.List$ListStyle: {
default: { fontColorUnselected: white, selection: selection, fontColorSelected: white, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Touchpad$TouchpadStyle: {
default: { background: default-pane, knob: default-round-large }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Tree$TreeStyle: {
default: { minus: tree-minus, plus: tree-plus, selection: default-select-selection }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextTooltip$TextTooltipStyle: {
default: {
    label: { font: default-font, fontColor: white },
    background: default-pane
}
},
}
```

MainMenu.java:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

Stage menu;
Skin uiskin;
TextButton button;

@Override
public void show() {

    setup();

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    menu.act();
    menu.draw();

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    dispose();
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    menu.dispose();

}

public boolean setup(){

    menu = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
    uiskin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("UISkin/uiskin.json"));

    button = new TextButton("Click me", uiskin, "default");

    button.setWidth(200f);
    button.setHeight(20f);
    button.setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() /2 - 100f, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2 - 10f);

    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y){
            button.setText("You clicked the button");
        }
    });

    menu.addActor(button);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(menu);

    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Did you forget to also include the uiskin.png and uiskin.atlas files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the `uiskin.atlas` file which I pulled from the GitHub page.

Suggested by @Tenfour04

Comment: Please accept this as an answer so I can flag it as a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62968275/how-to-fix-error-reading-json-file-in-libgdx).